# JSON formatting in Apex

Tags: java, json, apex, apex-code

I am getting a JSON in below format:

```
{
"A":"1",
"B":"2"
}
```

I have a field update and JSON at some point could be too long.
How can I change the JSON format to below pattern?

```
{"A":"1","B":"2"}
```

I am trying to store this minified JSON format on a field, so that char limit issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deserialize the string and serialize it again and then update the field.
Declare the JSON as string

```
Map<String,Object> parser = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(yourstring);
yourstring = JSON.serialize(parser);
```

You can change Map accordingly. Required format will be present in string variable.